# how to select not-null values from Oracle (optimized method)

Tags: oracle, merge, listagg

how can I select not null values from table ...

lets image table as follows:

```
master_id |     date_update     | name  |  dpt  | channel | source | active
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    1     |   1/2/2015 15:43:21 | NULL  |  NULL |  NULL   |   NULL |    y
    1     |   1/2/2015 15:43:21 | NULL  |  FIN  |  NULL   |   NULL |    n
    1     |   1/2/2015 15:40:16 | Elvis |  NULL |  NULL   |   NULL |    n
    1     |   1/2/2015 15:26:38 | NULL  |  NULL |  CH1    |   NULL |    n
    1     |   1/2/2015 14:57:02 | NULL  |  NULL |  NULL   |    S1  |    n
    5     |   2/2/2015 15:28:02 | NULL  |  NULL |  CH2    |   NULL |    y
    5     |   1/2/2015 10:13:01 | Sarah |  NULL |  NULL   |   NULL |    n
```

The result I would like to get is:

```
master_id |     date_update     | name  |  dpt  | channel | source | active
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    1     |   1/2/2015 15:43:21 | Elvis |  FIN  |  CH1    |   S1   |    y 
    5     |   2/2/2015 15:28:02 | Sarah |  NULL |  CH2    |   NULL |    y
```

You can notice, that DATE_UPDATE and ACTIVE column is the latest one ...

Which method is the most optimized one?
I tried the combination of **listagg** (to merge rows into one) and then get the last informations via **row_number() over()** or **max() over()** but I am not sure if it is the best performance solution ... joins are also not the best solution (because there are 17 columns I need to merge) ..

Comment: Can we assume that for a given column and `master_id` group, the data will be sparse with respect to `NULL` values, meaning that there would be only one non `NULL` value in that column?  Also, are you always choosing the _latest_ `date_update` for each `master_id` group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Oracle `MAX()` aggregate function should ignore `NULL` values, meaning it should pick up on the non `NULL` value in each `master_id` group as being the "max" for that column/group.

```
SELECT master_id, MAX(date_update), MAX(name), MAX(dpt), MAX(channel), MAX(source),
    MAX(active)
FROM image
GROUP BY master_id
```

Comment: that's what I was thinking about :) but what is the performance?

Comment: Rather than the performance of the query, I think the structure of the table might be the bigger concern.  Your table is _sparse_, meaning that it has a lot of unused space.  Do you plan to run this query often in a production setting?

Comment: I understand what you mean ... the problem is the incorrect application behavior :( I am trying to fix this "bug" with that query, which will serve as data_mart for reporting ... you know, kind of data consolidation ...